# Can the Grave Domain Cleric's "Sentinel at deaths door" cancel the autocrit from hitting an unconscious person?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, critical-hit, unconscious

The Grave Domain Cleric's *Sentinel at Death's Door* class feature has the following wording:

> At 6th level, you gain the ability to impede death’s progress. As a reaction when you or an ally that you can see within 30 feet of you suffers a critical hit, you can turn that attack into a normal hit. Any effects triggered by a critical hit are canceled.

PHB pg 292 describes the unconscious condition:

- An unconscious creature is incapacitated (see the condition), can’t move or speak, and is unaware of its surroundings
- The creature drops whatever it’s holding and falls prone.
- The creature automatically fails Strength and Dexterity saving throws.
- Attack rolls against the creature have advantage.
- **Any attack that hits the creature is a critical hit if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature.**

Does this mean that, RAW, a grave cleric could make it so a pc would only lose one death save from the hit, instead of two?

Comment: Also, welcome! I don't have the handy links of the fancy official greeters, but make sure to take the tour and read all the important stuff. We're glad you're here!

Comment: Here’s the fancy links @LCooper mentioned. Please check out the [tour] and the [help]. (Note for L Cooper, you can do this simply by doing `[tour] ` for the tour and `[help] ` to link to the help center)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### Yes, the PC protected by *Sentinel at Death's Door* will take a single death saving throw failure

It's pretty straightforward if we look at all the pieces in sequence, and most of the citations are already in the question.

A creature at 0 hit points is, generally, subject to the *Unconscious* condition, which transforms any hit into a critical as long as the attacker is within 5 feet:

> Any attack that hits the creature is a critical hit if the attacker is within 5 feet of the creature. (*PHB*, Appendix A: Conditions, Unconscious)

When it applies, the *Sentinel at Death's Door* feature transforms a critical hit into a normal hit:

> As a reaction when you or an ally that you can see within 30 feet of you suffers a critical hit, you can turn that attack into a normal hit. Any effects triggered by a critical hit are canceled. (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, Chapter 1: Subclasses, Cleric, Grave Domain, Grave Domain Features)

So a critical hit becomes a normal hit when this feature is activated. The remaining question is what happens on a regular hit to a creature at 0 HP:

> If you take any damage while you have 0 hit points, you suffer a death saving throw failure. If the damage is from a critical hit, you suffer two failures instead. If the damage equals or exceeds your hit point maximum, you suffer instant death. (*PHB*, Chapter 9: Combat, Damage and Healing, Dropping to 0 Hit Points, Death Saving Throws, Damage at 0 Hit Points)

So in summary:

- The two death saving throw failures are a result of the creature at 0
  HP taking a critical hit, but only one failure would be imposed on a
  non-critical hit
- A critical hit is automatic (under some circumstances) for an
  unconscious creature target, but this class feature converts a
  critical hit to a normal hit
- And so if the feature is used then the critical hit becomes a normal
  hit, and the creature at 0 HP suffers the effects of the normal hit
- That effect is a single, automatic failure on a death saving throw

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this will cancel the auto-crit.

Specific rules take precedence over general ones, and Sentinel at Death's Door, being a class feature, is more specific than the rules for death-saving throws.

Sentinel at Death's Door specifies that it can be activated "when you or an ally that you can see within 30 feet of you **suffers** a critical hit" (emphasis mine), meaning that its activation is based on when the critical hit is endured by the target, not by a critical hit being rolled.

The loss of two death saves to a critical hit is an *effect* caused by the critical hit, and therefore, that effect will be cancelled.